# Adding `post_author` in php

Tags: php

So, I have following markup to show a shortcode:

```
<div class="my_edit_button">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[something]'); ?>
</div>
```

Then I am trying to make it so that the shortcode is only shown to post author by using the following:

```
return ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID);
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate both into one.

Could someone help me out?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="my_edit_button">
<?php if ( $post->post_author == $current_user->ID ) {
echo do_shortcode('[something]'); 
}?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A neater solution would be to wrap all of the logic and markup into the shortcode itself:

```
function conditional_shortcode_wpse_188037() {
  global $post;
  if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {
    $ret =  '<div class="my_edit_button">';
      $ret .= 'other shortcode content';
    $ret .= '</div>';
    return $ret;
  }
}
add_shortcode('something','conditional_shortcode_wpse_188037');
```